# Valores de $_REQUEST retornando null

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte `form` que envia um array:

Formulário:

```
    <form id="form-simulacao" action="controller.php">
<div  class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-field">        
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nº do Fixo:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fixo['numero']">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Gasto Atual:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fixo['g_atual_fixo']">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Quanto gostaria de gastar:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fixo['deseja_fixo']">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <button class="btn btn-default">envia</button>
        </form>
```

```
Array
(
    [fixo] => Array
        (
            ['numero'] => xxxxx
            ['g_atual_fixo'] => yyyy
            ['deseja_fixo'] => 2
        )

)
```

eu preciso pegar o campo: `deseja_fixo`
então faço o seguinte no meu `php`:

```
$val = $_REQUEST['fixo']['deseja_fixo'];
echo $val;
```

só que ai não imprime nada na minha tela e quando faço `var_dump($val),` tenho `NULL` como resposta.

Comment: array(1) {
  ["fixo"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["'numero'"]=>
    string(5) "xxxxx"
    ["'g_atual_fixo'"]=>
    string(4) "yyyy"
    ["'deseja_fixo'"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}

Comment: insira o código de seu formulário de envio, ajuda na compreensão do problema!

Comment: @HenriqueSilva faz um teste assim $val =  (string)$_REQUEST['fixo']['deseja_fixo'];

Comment: retornar `NULL`

Comment: Valeu pelas dicas pessoal consegui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve tirar as aspas dos nomes dos campos do form ficando assim:

`name="fixo[deseja_fixo]"` e não assim  `name="fixo['deseja_fixo']"`

Comment: Obrigado cara eu estava super estressado já, horas perdidas por causa de aspas kkkkk

Comment: Já aconteceu isso comigo, por conta das aspas :-)